# I get notified of my own comments on my moderator nomination

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, comments

So the moderator election stuff is obviously "weird" and not stress tested like the rest of the system, and I don't even know if this is worth fixing.  But, I got notified when I commented on my own nomination, which doesn't make sense; just like anywhere else, I already know that I made a post (promise!).

<sub>I apologize for filling Meta with bug posts and other not-about-site-content posts today.  If there is a better alternative kindly let me know and I will do that instead.

Edit: It's fine, this is what meta is for, after all.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bug was found when replying to another user - it should have been sent to the reply target but was instead sent to the comment owner.  This will be fixed in the next deploy.